# Using datatables.net with VisualForce Pages

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, standardcontroller, datatables.js

I read from a contributor about using https://datatables.net/ for tables in VF pages.  I have the need to sort out a child related list called "**Labor_Items__c**".  Since I am using standard controllers without controller extensions (using Professional Edition), I thought I could achieve the user sorting requirements of this Labor_Items list by using this datatables.net plug-in.  My code is below.  It looks like the JS portion does not work.  What am I missing? The related list is rendering. But, the order is random. So, the datatables.net plug-in is not working.  Any help, it will be appreciated.

```
<apex:page readOnly="true"     
           standardController="NCQuote__c"
           showHeader="false"
           sidebar="false"
           standardStyleSheets="false"
           applyBodyTag="false"
           applyHtmlTag="false" > 
<html>
<head>
<!-- LIBRARY REFERENCE  -->     
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery}"/>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></link>
    
<style>
body        {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;
                vertical-align: middle; max-width:720px; margin:auto; padding:10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>    
    
    <table id="laborItems">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Mark</th>
                <th>Total Line Item</th>
                <th>Year</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <apex:repeat value="{!NCQuote__c.Labor_Item_relationship__r}" var="o">
                <tr>
                    <td><apex:outputField value="{!o.Name}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:outputField value="{!o.Mark__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:outputField value="{!o.Total_Line_Item_Process__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyy}"><apex:param value="{!o.CreatedDate}" /></apex:outputText></td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#laborItems').dataTable({
            'order': [1,'desc'],
            'paging' : false,
            'searching' : false
         });
    });
    </script>  
    
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [doc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order), the `order` option is an array of arrays

so you need this:

```
$('#laborItems').dataTable({
        'order': [[1,'desc']],
        'paging' : false,
        'searching' : false
     });
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out @cropredy.  

I was able to make it work the way I had it by downloading the Zip file from dataTables and uploading it as a static resource.  I changed my reference to the following:  

`<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery}"/>
   
<apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.DataTables,'DataTables-1.11.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}"/> 

<apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.DataTables,'DataTables-1.11.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css')}"/> `

Comment: By the way, I had an error above referencing the CSS stylesheet file.  It should be this way: <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.DataTables,'DataTables-1.11.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css')}"/>

Comment: @cpaesano - please post as an answer your complete solution as a service to the Community

Answer (score 0):

Final code below.

```
<apex:page readOnly="true"     
           standardController="NCQuote__c"
           showHeader="false"
           sidebar="false"
           standardStyleSheets="false"
           applyBodyTag="false"
           applyHtmlTag="false" > 
<html>
<head>
<!-- LIBRARY REFERENCE: Stored as static resources on Salesforce --> 
<!-- jquery was uploaded as a single file --> 
<!-- datatables .js and .css were uploaded as a zip file.  Notice the difference to access them. Make sure you point out the right folder tree path -->      
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery}"/>
<apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.DataTables,'DataTables-1.11.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}"/> 
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.DataTables,'DataTables-1.11.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css')}"/> 
    
<style>
body        {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;
                vertical-align: middle; max-width:720px; margin:auto; padding:10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   
    <table id="laborItems">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Mark</th>
                <th>Total Line Item</th>
                <th>Year</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <apex:repeat value="{!NCQuote__c.Labor_Item_relationship__r}" var="o">
                <tr>
                    <td><apex:outputField value="{!o.Name}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:outputField value="{!o.Mark__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:outputField value="{!o.Total_Line_Item_Process__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyy}"><apex:param value="{!o.CreatedDate}" /></apex:outputText></td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#laborItems').dataTable({
            'order': [1,'desc'],
            'paging' : false,
            'searching' : false
         });
    });
    </script>  
    
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```